# Javascript authorization(not authentication)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, authorization

we have web single page business app using knockout
In this app we have authorization page with permissions for every user.
E.g. Alex can Search at page "Partners" but Olla can also create a partner at this page.
It means that for Alex we need to hide button "Create Partner".
It is simple case.

More complicated case with dynamic created data table.
Each data row can have buttons or links with actionns and that was created at front end. So we need to apply authorization as well.

Yes we have backend authorization, but also want to hide not allowed action buttons.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You could search in google something like this:  `web application return pages on user roles`.  In ASP.NET, for example, they use roles (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32yf0a9.aspx).  This is not a knockout question, because the work is done in the server; is the server that returns web pages that only some users can see.  This web pages can have jQuery, Knockout,...

Comment: This is not Role authorization. It is more customizable. One user in same user group can do Action1, but cannot Action2.

Comment: Of course, it was only an idea how to do it.

Comment: Your question as it stands is likely to get closed. As @programtreasures has said, you should provide an example of what you have tried so far and not leave it so open ended and broad. The answer from Alexander Clayton is a good solution for accomplishing this with Knockout.js.

Comment: It seems nobody replied don't understand this task. Even Alexander Clayton answer not correct. Page can have 20 buttons. UserA allowed 15, but UserB 12. Both of them same user group

Answer (score 1):

You could inject the user's role as a parameter into your view model and then use it in an if or visible binding in your html. For example

```
var ViewModel = function(role) { 
    this.role = role;
... };

ko.ApplyBindings(new ViewModel({inject user role into html here }));

<button data-bind="if: role === 'createPartner'">Create</button>
```

Comment: This solution don't hides this options.  In the browser, if you show the html code, then you could see the hidden options.  The solution is that the server returns an web page that has only the options the user can see.  :-)

Comment: Jose, one more time. It is impossible what you say. Many controls are created at front end. For example ajax returns data and render occures at client side. Every row has many controls. we need to hide some of them for some users

Comment: If you have a menu with 20 options, and some user can see only four of then, the ajax request must return only this four options.  If it returns the 20, the user can see the hidden ones.  If this is correct to you, then I misunderstood your question, I'm sorry.  :-)